# jQuery Materialize Css Tabs next button

Tags: jquery, materialize

I am looking to move to the next tab in the index by clicking a button. I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $('ul.tabs').tabs();
             $('#btnContinue').click(function(){
                     $('ul.tabs').tabs("select", 'tab2');
             });
});
```

Which is working and move to the second tab: tab2

I am looking for a fixed button that would get the current id of the tab and then once clicking on the button would add 1 to it and move to the following one. (tab3,tab4)

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the tabs library? (https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: Yes. Tabs working great.

Answer (score 0):

use active `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: curIndex });`

```js
var tabContainer = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
var curIndex = 0;
    
$('#btnNext').click(function(){
    var tabsCount = $('#tabs ul li:visible').length;        
    curIndex = ((curIndex + 1) > 2) ? 0 : curIndex = curIndex + 1;
    tabContainer.tabs({ active: curIndex });

});

//direct click tab get index
tabContainer.tabs({
    activate: function (e, ui) {
        curIndex = ui.newTab.index();
    }
});
/*tabContainer.bind("tabsactivate", function (event, ui) {
  curIndex = ui.newTab.index();
});
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div>
<button id='btnNext'>
Next
</button>
</div>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me. I'm trying to understand what exactly not working on my side, where should I start?

Comment: @talElm press F12 check developer tool . Do you get  error ??

Comment: Yes, looks like: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
on line:
tabContainer.bind("tabsactivate", function (event, ui) {

Comment: @talElm what  version of jquery ui and jquery in your project ?

Comment: jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Comment: @talElm And version of jquery ui ?

Comment: I use 1.12.0 for the jQuery UI

Comment: @talElm I modified code snippet. check it ! call event `activate` to return index. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taiwanhotdog/p6mqwj1L/1/)